# Unresolved external symbol - win32 function

Tags: qt, winapi, qt-creator, unresolved-external

I am trying to compile a project using Qt Creator. But I get error for win32 function.

> -1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FlashWindow@8 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall Proj::runBs(int,long)" (?runBs@Proj@@AAEXHJ@Z)

`win32:LIBS += -luser32` did not help.

Comment: Use *User32.lib*

Comment: @RbMm `win32:LIBS += User32.Lib` did not help.

Comment: Well, show the entire linker command line that your build process runs.  Not the rules themselves, fixing those can come later -- the actual command line resulting from the rules.

Comment: @BenVoigt `qmake: qmake.exe Proj.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"`

Comment: That's not a linker command line.  Looking for the one that starts with "link.exe" (possibly with a path)

Comment: @BenVoigt can't find

Comment: Should I assume that for debugging you commented out function calls in your code and you are just trying to compile with the lib linked. .. so you are using MSVC kit ? which version .. and what architecture your windows is?  can you show a screen shot of your kit under creator?

Comment: @MohammadKanan https://imgur.com/a/MPFkrms  Windows7, x86.

Comment: well, all your kits are "red marked" .. not a good sign. Now hover mouse over the kit in question, you will see a popup rectangle indicating what the problem in your kit is .. lets see whats that?

Comment: I can tell its a wrong debugger configuration .. but lets see what else you might have

Comment: @MohammadKanan https://imgur.com/a/GbGXDkn

Comment: The Error is clear though. was the compiler auto detected?  if so, just remove configured debugger and see if error disappears. you still have a warning for compiler though.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PEKCfQ6 when I start debugging for both debugger options.